# How to display text in the middle?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I wanna display text of my article in the middle of the screen but keep the image size large. I am using Wordpress hence I can add custom CSS to it.

How do I do this? Padding or adding margin doesn't work as it also adds it to the images. Since I am using Wordpress this seems harder. The images are automatically getting enclosed with the article-body tag and also in the paragraph tag. What do I do? You can see the text in the screenshot below, which is from medium.com is in the middle so as it is really cool and easy to read but at the same time the images are quite large and bigger than the text. I am unable to do this in my wordpress site.

Adding padding or margin affects the images. Align-centre doesn't work.

[image: This is from a screen grab from medium.com's article.]

Comment: Please provide the `HTML` and `CSS` relevant to the issue.

Comment: #element { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; } --- Should work fine. If it doesn't work, wrap your items inside a container.

Comment: div[itemprop="articleBody"] p{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
   margin: auto 0;
   width: 600px; }

defensionem.com/2015/09/14/us-military-demo-3 This is my site. Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
text-align:center;
margin: auto 0;
```

**UPDATE:**

Replace the .body-text with the below:

```
.body-text {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
```

If you want to center the text remove text-align: center; as the instyle within the paragraph like so:

```
<p id="6d1a" class="graf--p">
```

Reducing the width will change the width of the image so end the body-text before the image like so:

```
  <div class="body-text clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">

      <p id="6d1a" class="graf--p" style="/* text-align: left; */">
The U.S. national security space communit.....</p>
    </div>
```

Then place image outside of the body-text div.

Then include paragraph within body-text like so:

```
 <div class="body-text clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
The strategy includes a st...</div>
```

Implementing this will give you something like the following:

[image]

Comment: div[itemprop="articleBody"] p{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
   margin: auto 0;
   width: 600px;

} Code I used

Comment: Yes, this works, but how do I get the image size to be large? Thanks a ton Kadeem. Like Full Width. Or Larger images.

Comment: Good. Ok, if you place an end </div> tag after the text; just before the image it should change width.